# Errors while creating a power function

Tags: haskell, math

First of all, I want to say that I'm very very inexperienced with Haskell, and I know that I have done something (or multiple things) terribly wrong, been struggling for hours but I can't seem to find it.

```
power :: Int -> Int -> Int
power x y | y == 0 = 1
          | x == 0 = 0
list = replicate y x
foldr (*) x list
main = print $ power 3 5
```

Error most of the time is either x and y not being passed to the replicate function or that foldr is a naked function, I understand what they both mean but have no idea on how I can pass the variables or come up with a solution.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You here created four functions: `power`, `list`, `foldr` and `main`. But you use variables `x` and `y` in the definition of the `list` function.

You can work with a `where` clause to specify subexpressions, for example:

```
power :: Int -> Int -> Int
power x y | y == 0 = 1
          | x == 0 = 0
          | otherwise = foldr (*) 1 list
    where list = replicate y x
```

or perhaps more elegant with pattern matching:

```
power :: Int -> Int -> Int
power 0 _ = 0
power x y = foldr (*) 1 (replicate y x)

main = print $ power 3 5
```

Here we can also eliminate the case for *x<sup>0</sup>*, since our `foldr` starts working with `1`, not `x`.

This algorithm is however not very efficient, since it is linear in the value of `y`. By checking recursively if the exponent is even or odd, you can make it faster. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: I think I'd prefer `foldr (*) 1 (replicate y x)`. As a general rule it's nice to use an operation's (right-)identity element as the base case, I think.

Comment: @DanielWagner: yes, updated! Perhaps it is also more efficient to work with `foldl` here?

Answer (score 2):

You were very close! The main things that need to be fixed are:

- When writing a definition with guards, the “fallback” case needs to be a guard as well, conventionally written with `otherwise`.

  Recall that a definition without guards looks like this, with one left side (a name and parameter patterns/names) and one right side (an expression):

  ```
  name patterns             = expression
  ```

  With guard conditions, there is one right-hand side for each guard:

  ```
  name patterns | condition1 = expression1
                | condition2 = expression2
                …
                | otherwise  = expressionn
  ```

  `otherwise` is really just an alias for `True`, that is, such a guard always matches. The only thing special about `otherwise` is that the compiler uses it as a hint when analysing whether a pattern match covers all possible cases.
- In order to define a variable `list`, local to the definition of `power`, using the parameters `x` and `y`, you need to use either a `let`…`in`… expression, that is, `let block in expression`, or a `where` clause, `equation where block`. A *block* is a series of items (in this case, local definitions) which must all be written starting at the same column of indentation, or be delimited by explicit curly braces `{`…`}` and semicolons `;`.

Using `let`…`in`… follows the structure of your original code pretty closely. I will adjust the indentation style to avoid needing to align anything, by putting a newline and a constant amount of indentation instead.

```
power :: Int -> Int -> Int
power x y
    | y == 0 = 1
    | x == 0 = 0
    | otherwise = let
        list = replicate y x
    in foldr (*) x list

main :: IO ()
main = print $ power 3 5
```

Attaching a `where` clause to an equation is slightly more common than using a `let`…`in`… expression on the right side of an equation.

```
power :: Int -> Int -> Int
power x y
    | y == 0 = 1
    | x == 0 = 0
    | otherwise = foldr (*) x list
    where
        list = replicate y x

main :: IO ()
main = print $ power 3 5
```

Note that in this case, there is a slight difference: the variable `list` is visible in *all* of the right-hand sides, although we only use it in one of them. With `let list = … in e`, `list` is only defined within `e`. In general, it’s helpful for readability to keep the scope of a variable as small as possible, although you can certainly go overboard:

```
a = …
  where
    b = …
      where
        c = …
          where
            d = …
              -- If you see this much nesting, rethink!
```

If you run into issues with alignment and indentation, you can always use explicit delimiters instead. The code I wrote is equivalent to the following.

```
power :: Int -> Int -> Int;    -- Begin ‘power’ signature.
power x y
    | y == 0 = 1
    | x == 0 = 0
    | otherwise = let {        -- Begin ‘let’ block.
        list = replicate y x;  -- End ‘list’ equation.
    } in foldr (*) x list;     -- End ‘let’ block, then end ‘power’ equation.

main :: IO ();                 -- Begin ‘main’ signature.
main = print $ power 3 5;      -- End ‘main’ equation.
```

Or similarly with `where { … }`.

Comment: Why did you `lang-none` the code blocks in the middle of the answer?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: The syntax highlighting deleted the emphasis, so I made an executive decision about which one I wanted to prioritise.

Comment: Huh? Weird. Markup emphasis _used to_ work in syntax-highlighted `<code>` blocks.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: It might yet, but was borked in the preview at least, lemme futz with it

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I figure it’s likely a bug, so I’ve opened a question about it on Meta: [Inline formatting no longer works with syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408921/246886)